How do I run multiple files on node.js?
I have a school project that I am working on, and I'm planning to use Node.js to host it. The thing is, every time I try to run it, it returns nothing.
I have 4 HTML, 2 CSS, and 2 JS files in one folder, and I'm trying to host all the HTML files.
My node.js script:
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=8080; 

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

    if (err) throw err;    

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
})

But the terminal doesn't return anything.

What are you expecting "the terminal [to] return"? Your script doesn't log anything to the terminal, it appears to start an http server on port 8080 that only serves the index html file. Does it do what you expect when you visit localhost:8080?

#1 Do you have 4 files like:  index1.html,  index2.html,  index3.html,  index4.html ?

Please change the title to : How do host multiple html files with node.js?

Note
Your code is not suitable to host web pages neither simple nor complex.
Anyway I will explain you how to solve your problem using your code and I will show you another pro tips
Using your code
Your code is working. Just go to http://localhost:8080/ to validate it

But if you have other files like foo.html , your code will not work. You could add more fs.readFile and a logic to render them like
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

async function main(){

const PORT=8080; 

    var page1 = await fs.promises.readFile('./index.html');
    var page2 = await fs.promises.readFile('./index2.html');
    var page3 = await fs.promises.readFile('./index3.html');

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        var pageContent;
        if(request.url=="/" || request.url.endsWith("index.html")){
            pageContent = page1;
        }else if(request.url.endsWith("index2.html")){
            pageContent = page2;
        }else if(request.url.endsWith("index3.html")){
            pageContent = page3;
        }else {
            pageContent = "Page not found";
        }
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(pageContent);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
}

main();

Result

As you can see, it works but you need to add more logic for every new files (css, js, fonts, etc) which doesn't make sense. Anyway If you insist to code from the scratch (which could help you to understand how complex is a real server) you could use the library called express :
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the port of our application
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// make express look in the public directory for assets (css/js/img)
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/web"));

// set the home page route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Our app is running on ' + port);
});

And then in the web folder put all your files (js, css, fonts, etc) and you N html files

Notes

To access the others files which are not the index.html , use something like http://localhost:8080/foo.html
Complete code here https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-static-pages

More simple ways with nodejs
node-static
Library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static
Usage:
In your folder which contains all your files, execute
npm install -g node-static
static

Then go to http://localhost:8080
Notes

There are a lot of option to serve a static page with nodejs. Just research with : How to host static page with nodejs
Also another languages like Python has the same features

Github Pages
If you need to show your page to your teacher or team outside of your laptop/pc, I can advice to use github pages. With this you could share the public link and others could see your web using internet.
More details

https://pages.github.com/
https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/github-pages
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BA_c3bGQXlQ

For Enterprises
There are another options used for real enterprises to host real web sites:

Apache
Nginx
AWS S3
Heroku
Cloudflare
A lot!!

